# Any explanations for poor Oracle / LINQ for Entities performance on this query? (C#)

Tags: c#, oracle, linq, entity-framework

I have an IQueryable variable 'v' which is an expression with existing filtering which refers to around 2000 records (at most) that can be returned in under a second from Oracle.

I have 2 versions of the remaining query:

```
  var values = v.Where(x => x.END_DATE != null)
    .GroupBy(x => new { Rate = x.PRICE_NOTATION.Value, ExpiryDate = x.END_DATE.Value })
    .Select(y => new
    {
       NotionalSum = y.Sum(z => z.ROUNDED_NOTIONAL_AMOUNT_1),
       Rate = y.Key.Rate,
       ExpiryDate = y.Key.Rate
    })
    .ToArray();
```

and the following version

```
  var values = v.Where(x => x.END_DATE != null).Select(x => new
    {
       Notional_Amount = x.ROUNDED_NOTIONAL_AMOUNT_1,
       Rate = x.PRICE_NOTATION.Value,
       ExpiryDate = x.END_DATE.Value
    })
  .GroupBy(x => new { Rate = x.Rate, ExpiryDate = x.ExpiryDate })
  .ToArray();
```

The first groups then selects, the second selects then groups. The first returns in under a second, while the second returns generally in over a minute.

What I'm trying to work out is why the second one is so slow. I mean, if I just replace the v with v.ToArray() at the start of the second version (to just load all the records matched by expression 'v' into memory), that query returns in under 2  seconds.
I can't outline the company's views and database structure, but can anyone offer any ideas as to particular issues within Oracle or its Linq to EF mappings which might explain this massive difference in performance?

Comment: Take a look at the SQL generated from each query.  That can shed some light into what's going on.

Comment: The second query is returning more data than the first.  Rather than summing the amount and returning one amount per group, it's getting all of the amounts for those values and returning them.  That could potentially be an issue, although I wouldn't normally expect it to be *that* big of an issue.  If you use the second argument to `GroupBy` to map the results to the key plus the sum of the amounts does that fix the problem?

Comment: To be frank, I've had a go at tracing the generated SQL from some other queries, but while that then enabled me to optimise the SQL query itself, it didn't necessarily help much in writing a LINQ statement that generated a better Oracle query. The latter drops off some of the logic performed in the first (leaving it to in-memory), and it's still vastly slower. As noted in the question, if I add v.ToArray() then the second will load even more into memory, but returns much faster, so I know it's not that, hence wondering what it might be

Comment: Not knowing the actual data involved, I suspect that it is because the first one groups the data which returns a much smaller set to the caller.  The second returns a larger data set to the caller, then groups them.

Comment: @NebulaSleuth The grouping is done in the DB end in either case.

Comment: @DavidBurton I'm not necessarily saying you should go around editing the generated SQL to optimizing it, but looking at what it is can help you understand what types of things in a LINQ query happen to end up generating unperformant SQL, or it can help you realize differences in what the two queries are doing that aren't as apparent in the LINQ code.  Another thing it can do is tell you if there is some operation that couldn't be performed in the DB and is instead being done in memory, when you would *expect* it to be done by the query provider.

Comment: The latter is the one that is confusing me... if I just return all the 'v' records into memory, I'm loading more data from the database to the client, but that's still 30x (or more) faster than doing the grouping on the database. I'm trying to figure out how Oracle can manage to spend up to 2 minutes working on a single select query loading data from a view with just 5000 records in total